# How can I check with a condition if one of the leaflet layers is selected?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

This is how I added some base layers to the map. Mapbox and OpenStreetMap are some of them.

```
var baseLayers = {        
    "Mapbox Satellite": L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets-satellite'),
    "Mapbox Streets": L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets'),
    "Mapbox Outdoors": L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.outdoors'),
    "OpenStreetMap Standard": L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution:'<div class="basemap_link" >&copy;\n\
                    <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap contributors. </a>\n\
                    <a href="https://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use" target="_blank">Website and API terms</a>\n\
                    </div>'   
    })
    baseLayers['Mapbox Satellite'].addTo(map);
```

I added a layer modifier control to the map (top left)

```
L.control.layers(baseLayers, null, {
position: 'topleft',}).addTo(map);
L.control.locate().addTo(map);
L.control.fullscreen().addTo(map);
```

I want to create different styles for each layer. How can I check with a condition if one of these brochure layers is selected (marked as a radio button)?

Comment: "_I want to create different styles for each layer_" what is the link with "_How can I check with a condition if one of these brochure layers is selected_"?

Comment: It takes it from Mapbox's own ready-made javascript library.

Comment: Can I check with condition if layer is selected or not using baselayers name?                For example **['Mapbox Satellite']**